# sending messages containing not predefined types

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.
I took a look at how custom messages can be designed in ROS and I realized that they can just include fields of predefined types (for instance, integers and strings).
Instead, I have two active nodes needing to communicate with each other. One of them, produces a list of objects belonging to a class that I have defined. This list should be sent to the other node but I guess it's not possible using standard ROS messages.
Could you suggest a way to bypass the problem, maybe using possible definitions of ROS messages?

Thanks for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50372/sending-messages-containing-not-predefined-types/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Custom messages can contain other (custom and predefined) messages. That's a required and widely used feature in ROS.

Example:

Message `MyCustomMessage` in package foo:

```
string name
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped pose
```

Message ObjectList:

```
 foo/MyCustomMessage[] objects
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-13**:
hi, thanks for answer. just to be sure: you are telling me that I can have a field of superclass Object[] in my custom message?
It would be amazing. Why this possibility is not shown here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg ?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-13**:
Not really a "superclass", more a "containment" relation. One message can contain fields defined by other messages. I agree that the wiki should explain it explicitly. Maybe open a defect ticket for the wiki.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-13**:
Maybe `Object` was not the best choice for the example. You could replace object here by `MyCustomMsgType`.

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-13**:
ok, I knew about encapsulation of message. Anyway, I guess that the most encapsulated message in the hierarchy has to contain simple types listed in wiki guide. so, for trying to understand better, if I have an object List, where Node is a class defined by me, how should a message appear...

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-13**:
... to contain that list?
thanks for your support.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-13**:
mypkg/Node[] nodes

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-14**:
ok.i created a message in a file:

int id
scan_node[] sc_nodes
odom_node[] od_nodes

i saved it as measurement.msg in my pachage's directory msg I uncommented rosbuild_genmsg() in CMakeLists file and I got this error:...

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-14**:
... IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/beginner/msg/int.msg'
what happened?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-14**:
There is not `int` message type. Please read the message docs: http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-14**:
ok, thanks. I corrected the first line. now a new error:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/beginner/msg/scan_node.msg'
how to make system find the classes/header defined in my src directory? I tried to specify a path, but it didn't work

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-14**:
... I got /home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/beginner/scr/scan_node[] is not a legal message type

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-14**:
You need to define a `scan_node` message.

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-14**:
is it possible to define a list of messages as a field of a message?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-14**:
Yes, just look at @Lorenz' answer.